# How to compile in Eclipse so I can use outside? (without opening eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

I searched for an answer but didn't found it, so here it goes.

When I try to execute the program from cmd (with javac, I guess), I get this error:

```
D:\Libraries\workspace\bucky\bin\bucky>java apples
         Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: apples (wrong name:bucky/apples)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I wanted to be able to send the application to my friends. I'm very new to this, so if it's a stupid question, it's because I only started a few days ago. I'm using java.util.Locale and java.util.Scanner if that is important. If I need to past the code, tell me. It's about 130 lines.

Thanks (If you noticed, I'm learning on Youtube, "thenewboston" is the user that made the turorials)

Comment: Please post error messages as text in your question, not as images, and definitely not as linked images.

Comment: Post your Java class. It appears most likely that you're using the wrong `java` command; perhaps it should be `bucky.apples` (and capitalize your Java class names).

Comment: Quite frankly, learning Java on youtube from a random person is not a good idea. Read a good book, or use the official tutorials by Oracle. Would you learn medicine from an unknown person's tutorials on Youtube?

Comment: @JB Nizet good point. But it's easier to understand, and it ins't an unknown person. He has a large amount of followers. Probably he is teaching right. If you could tell me a good book, I would take it in consideration.

Comment: It's been a loooong time I've learnt Java, but "Thinking in Java" by Bruce Eckel has a good reputation. Note that Justin Bieber also has a large amount of followers. That doesn't make it a good singer, IMHO :-)

Comment: @JB Nizet win. just win. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should post how you try to run your code and the error message here as text. Just copy and paste from the Windows cmd box -- easy to do:

> right click cmd window -> click select all -> press enter

and now it's copied to the clipboard.

It looks like you may be trying to run this without taking packages into consideration.

i.e., from the bin subdirectory, call `

```
otherDirectories/bin>java bucky.apples
```

But more importantly, if this were my project I'd have Eclipse export it first as a runnable jar file, and then simply run the jar file.

The menu order is:

> Right-click on Project -> Export -> Java -> Runnable Jar File

Comment: Ok. Exported. But I can't run it. What do I do now?

Comment: @EnderEgg: show us how you try to run the jar, and what problems you have with it.

Comment: As a jar, I was now able to run it from cmd, with "java -jar apples.jar". Thanks! Now another question... how can I run it without cmd? My friends aren't that into pcs like me.

Comment: @EnderEgg: a runnable jar file can be double-clicked from the windows explorer (if the JRE has been installed). You can also give them a .bat or .cmd file that they can double-click, which contains the appropriate java command.

Comment: Thanks lots! :D Used a .bat file just saying "start java -jar apples.jar"

Comment: if its on windows and you set up JRE right, you can just double click on it and it should start (but in this case without a java console).

Answer (score 1):

That should be really simple. Eclipse got an export dialog. I think it was at File -> Export. There you can choose you desination for your compiled JAR and which external JARS should be inlcuded (e. g. JDBC).